# How to recreate element (SWING)?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

In my form **I've created** JSpinner and JComboBox elements. Depending on the changing of JComboBox I have to use the different Spinner models. So in ComboBox listener I write *spinner = new JSpinner(newModel)*, but it **change nothing** on form.
How to recreate element to see the difference?

```
        // Create default Spinner
        count = new JSpinner();

        // Trying to replace spinner
        product.addActionListener(e -> {
            JComboBox source = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
            String selectedItem = (String) source.getSelectedItem();
            ...
            SpinnerNumberModel numberModel = getNewNumberModel(...)
            count = new JSpinner(numberModel);
            count.setModel(numberModel);
            // repaint(); revalidate() - also don't working
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not reallocate the spinner every time. Just replace its model. You are allocating a new instance of `JSpinner` in you action listener and change its model. But this new instance is not part of your panel and not visible. Remove `count = new JSpinner(numberModel);` from the action listener. And change the model of the existing spinner.